# Нужна помощь с кодом

Tags: javascript

Есть работающий код. Условия работают, но когда хочу вывести предупреждение: если ничего не ввести то во пусть выведет ошибка if (myAge === NaN) {alert ("Wrong")} у меня не работает. В чем проблема?

HTML

```
<input id="age" placeholder="Enter Your Age">
<button id="press">Перевірити мій вік</button>
```

JS

```
let pressing = document.getElementById('press');
pressing.onclick = function checkAge () {
let check = document.getElementById('age');
let myAge = check.value;
 if(myAge < 18){
alert('You are so young for this site');
}
if (myAge >= 18){
 alert('Welcome to our site');
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Это особенность арифметики с плавающей точкой<sup>*)</sup>. Специальное значение `NaN` не равно никакому другому значению, даже самому себе. Результат следующих выражений есть `false`:

```js
const nan = NaN;

console.log( nan <   0 );
console.log( nan === 0 );
console.log( nan >   0 );

console.log( nan <   nan );
console.log( nan === nan );
console.log( nan >   nan );
```

Но результат следующих выражений есть `true`:

```js
const nan = NaN;

console.log( nan !== nan );
console.log( isNaN(nan) );
console.log( Number.isNaN(nan) );
console.log( Object.is(nan, NaN) );
```

---

*) Стандарт арифметики с плавающей точкой `IEEE 754-2008` помимо всего прочего определяет операции сравнения над числами с плавающей точкой (1.3):

> This standard specifies:
> [...]
> ― Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, fused multiply add, square root, **compare**, and other operations.

Должна быть возможность сравнить два числа с плавающей точкой между собой. Причём возможны четыре взаимоисключающих отношения: *меньше* (*less than*), *равно* (*equal*), *больше* (*greater than*) и *неупорядочено* (*unordered*). Отношение «неупорядочено» возникает в том случае, если по крайней мере один из сравниваемых операндов — `NaN`. Он должен быть неупорядочен при сравнении с любым числом с плавающей точкой, даже при сравнении с самим собой. 5.11:

> For every supported arithmetic format, it shall be possible to compare one floating-point datum to another in that format (see 5.6.1). Additionally, floating-point data represented in different formats shall be comparable as long as the operands’ formats have the same radix.
>
> Four mutually exclusive relations are possible: *less than*, *equal*, *greater than*, and *unordered*. The last case arises when at least one operand is `NaN`. Every `NaN` shall compare *unordered* with everything, including itself. Comparisons shall ignore the sign of zero (so `+0 = −0`). Infinite operands of the same sign shall compare *equal*.

Один из способов, которым язык может предоставить возможность сравнить два числа с плавающей точкой — это специальные предикаты, возвращающие `true`/`false` в зависимости от того в каком из четырёх вышеописанных отношений находятся два сравниваемых числа с плавающей точкой. 5.11:

> Languages define how the result of a comparison shall be delivered, in one of two ways: either as a relation identifying one of the four relations listed above, or as a true-false response to a predicate that names the specific comparison desired.

Каждый предикат должен возвращать истину тогда, когда истинно любое из обозначаемых им отношений. В стандарте в виде таблиц представлены названия предикатов, несколько вариантов *операторов*, которыми в языках программирования могут обозначаться данные предикаты и списки отношений для каждого предиката, при истинности любого из которых, тот или иной предикат должен возвращать `true`. 5.11:

> Table 5.1, Table 5.2, and Table 5.3 exhibit twenty-two functionally distinct useful predicates and negations with various ad-hoc and traditional names and symbols. Each predicate is true if any of its indicated relations is true. The relation “?” indicates an *unordered* relation.

Таблица 5.1:

[image: IEEE 754-2008. Table 5.1]

Из таблицы видно, что предикат `compareQuietEqual`, который в некоторых языках программирования обозначается символом `=` (а в некоторых `==`, или даже `===`), должен возвращать `true`, если сравниваемые числа с плавающей точкой находятся в отношении *равно* (`EQ`, *equal*).
А предикат `compareQuietNotEqual` должен возвращать `true`, если сравниваемые числа находятся в одном из следующих отношений: *меньше* (`LT`, *less than*), *больше* (`GT`, *greater than*) или *неупорядочено* (`UN`, *unordered*).

Так как `NaN` неупорядочен при сравнении с любым числом с плавающей точкой (даже с самим собой), то предикат `compareQuietEqual` всегда вернёт `false`, если по крайней мере один из операндов — `NaN`. Предикат `compareQuietNotEqual` в свою очередь вернёт `true`.

Таблица 5.3:

[image: IEEE 754-2008 Table 5.3]

Из неё видно, что предикаты вида «больше», «больше либо равно», «меньше», «меньше либо равно» всегда вернут `false`, если хотябы один из операндов — `NaN`.

---

Теперь открываем [ECMAScript 2020 Language Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/).
Смотрим пункт [4.3.20 Number value](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value):

> Number value
> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754-2019 value
> Note
> A Number value is a member of the Number type and is a direct representation of a number.

[4.3.24 NaN](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-nan):

> NaN
> Number value that is an IEEE 754-2019 “Not-a-Number” value

Видим, что значения числового типа, включая `NaN` — это числа с плавающей точкой формата `IEEE 754-2019`. Ранее в ответе я ссылался на стандарт `IEEE 754-2008` (у меня нет текста более нового стандарта), но каких-либо изменений между этими двумя стандартами, оказывающих влияние на `ECMA-262`, нет. [G Bibliography / 1](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-bibliography):

> Note
> There are no normative changes between `IEEE 754-2008` and `IEEE 754-2019` that affect the ECMA-262 specification.

Посмотрим, например, как работает оператор строгого сравнения `===` для числового типа. [7.2.16 Strict Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison):

> The comparison `x === y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces `true` or `false`. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
> [...]
> If `Type(x)` is Number or BigInt, then
> Return !Type(x)::equal(x, y).

Смотрим, как работает `Number::equal(x, y)` ([6.1.6.1.13](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-numeric-types-number-equal)):

> 1. If x is NaN, return false.
> 2. If y is NaN, return false.
> 3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
> 4. If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
> 5. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
> 6. Return false.

Написано другими словами, но алгоритм соответствует `IEEE 754-2008` предикату `compareQuietEqual`.

Смотрим, как работает `Number::lessThan(x y)`, который используется при сравнении чисел оператором `<` ([6.1.6.1.12](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-numeric-types-number-lessThan)):

> 1. If x is NaN, return undefined.
> 2. If y is NaN, return undefined.
> 3. If x and y are the same Number value, return false.
> 4. If x is +0 and y is -0, return false.
> 5. If x is -0 and y is +0, return false.
> 6. If x is +∞, return false.
> 7. If y is +∞, return true.
> 8. If y is -∞, return false.
> 9. If x is -∞, return true.
> 10. If the mathematical value of x is less than the mathematical value of y—note that these mathematical values are both finite and not both zero—return true. Otherwise, return false.

C учётом того, что значение `undefined` (которое возвращается, если один из операндов `NaN`, что "подозрительно" похоже на *unordered* в `IEEE 754-2008`) в дальнейшем при вычислении `<` преобразуется в `false`, получем, что алгоритм работы оператора `<` для числовых операндов соответствует предикату `compareQuietLess`, хотя и описан другими словами.

Comment: а причем тут _Это особенность арифметики с плавающей точкой_?

Comment: @Grundy  `NaN` — это "число" с плавающей точкой.

Comment: но то, что оно не равно самому себе, никак к этому не относится.

Comment: @Grundy, то что оно не равно самому себе определяется стандартом IEEE 754, и стандарт ECMA-262 ему следует.

Comment: @Grundy, [ECMAScript, 4.3.24 `NaN`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-nan): `Number value that is an IEEE 754-2019 “Not-a-Number” value`.

Comment: Покажи это место в стандарте

Comment: @Grundy какое место в каком стандарте?

Comment: что _оно не равно самому себе определяется стандартом IEEE 754_

Comment: 1) Считаете, что совпадение алгоритмов работы с `NaN` у `ECMAScript` и `IEEE 754` — просто совпадение? 2) Вам нужна цитата из `IEEE 754`, что `NaN` не равен самому себе?

Comment: _Вам нужна цитата из IEEE 754, что NaN не равен самому себе?_ - именно в этом и был вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, добавил пару цитат в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать метод `Number.isNaN(...)` для проверки на `NaN`

```
if (!Number.isNaN(myAge)) {
    alert("Wrong");
}
```

Ещё замечу, что данные из всех инпутов возвращаются в строковом формате и надо приводить их к числу. Обычно делают так: `let myAge = +check.value;`. Но есть и другие способы.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло)